# DBeaver 22.1.5 will not recognize tables in SQL script but can still find them in schema explorer

Tags: sql, dbeaver

Dbeaver does not recognize tables written in SQL scripts, however the schema explorer seems to work fine and still shows correct schema and table information. This started occurring after my machine shut off unexpectedly. I am new to dbeaver, how do I resolve this? From a brief google search I can only seem to find other people having the opposite issue. I have already tried disconnecting and reconnecting to the database to no avail.